# Switching scenes at correct time in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

My question is about switching scenes on a UI. I am trying to switch scenes then reload my javafx program. I want a loading scene to appear before I refresh so the user knows that data is being loaded. Here is my code:

```
@FXML
private void restartValidation(ActionEvent e) throws IOException, InterruptedException, InvalidReferenceException {
    sceneResponsibilities.setVisible(true);
    sceneDeviceProperties.setVisible(false);
    sceneArticleNumbers.setVisible(false);
    sceneBusService.setVisible(false);
    sceneDTC.setVisible(false);
    sceneDP.setVisible(false);
    noErrors.setVisible(false);

    runInitializationOfValidation();
}
```

I want to be able to go from any scene to sceneResponsibilities before I reload data. Currently the code seems to directly go to `runInitializaitonOfValidation()`. When I go to debug mode it shows that all of the `setVisible` code is ran, but `sceneResponsibilities` is not shown on the UI. I have no clue why this is. Any ideas?

Comment: You're probably blocking the ui thread with `runInitializationOfValidation()` which results in the ui only being refreshed ***after*** the adjustments to the ui done by the `runInitializationOfValidation()` method are applied...

Comment: Okay thanks for the input I will try to fix it from doing that